# Codeigniter routing works in local but not in server (404)

Tags: codeigniter

The routing I'm using is working in local but not in server.

I have this controller which only loads a view :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CgvController extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('cgv');
    }
}
```

I can access it using example.com/index.php/CgvController/index (in local I can access it using only /CgvController/index), and I would like that when i'm writing example.com/cgv.html I get the same page.

My routes file is :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'IndexController';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['cgv\.html'] = 'CgvController/index';
```

Comment: change $config['baseurl']

Comment: I did, i have : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com'` but I'm still having 404

Comment: folder name is there or it is in public html

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Your default controller should be all lower case example `$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';`

Comment: I changed to `$route['default_controller'] = 'indexController';` but still have 404. For info if you don't write any method after the controller name, the index method is taken in priority.

Comment: means it is in the root or wihin any folder in public html

Comment: No the controller is in the controller folder, no sub folder. So I can get it via application/controllers/CgvController.php

Comment: Your class on controller is wrong should have only first letter upper case only same with file name.

Comment: Sorry but nothing says in the documentation that I can't have an uppercase in the middle of the class's name. I've tried without, nothing  has changed, still got a 404.